# synchronising fences and texture unloading

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, textures

My OpenGL application displays a 3D view where images are loaded on demand based on what is visible. The load operation send's a load request to the texture loader thread, which then does this:

```
...
    <Open image and read into an openGL texture = tex>

    // is this lock needed if this is one of multiple loader threads that each pass textures to the main thread? I.e is glClientWaitSync() thread-safe?
    {   
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mOpenGLClientWaitSyncMutex); 

         // we need to wait on a fence before alerting the primary thread that the Texture is ready
         glClientWaitSync(mSync, GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);

         // Pass texture to MAIN THREAD
         textureLoaderRequest->mContentViewer->setTexture(tex, requestFrameIndex);
    }
...
```

Note. A shared OpenGL context is created for each loader thread and associated with the main.

I have the following areas of uncertainty:

a) **OpenGL Fences.**
I must admit, I am still chewing over the OpenGL fences subject. At the moment there is only 1 texture loader thread, and the main thread. If I had multiple texture loader threads, would I need to synchronise the fence->clientWaitSync()'s? (or am I being daft here as would the clientWaitSync() in each loader thread provide the necessary sync guards for multiple threads setting a texture to be drawn on the main thread). I did some reading, added the above lock_guard, and a bit of testing and it didn't seem to affect anything. (but that doesn't usually mean anything, hence my question).

b) **Texture Unloading.**
My goal is to have another thread that performs the unloads to keep the UI smooth, whilst not delaying the IO related loader thread/s. Because I am creating the texture on the loader thread, what sort of context arrangement is required such that the unloader thread can unload it. I mean, at the moment they are all 'attached' to the main context, so I guess my question is whether the siblings need some sort of "direct" sharing arrangement, or are they already shared due to the association with the main opengl context? How would you tackle such a problem?